# Does animal food mekabel tumah?

Tags: food, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Does food which has a status of animal food only receive ritual impurity (mekabel tumah)? please bring a source.

Comment: Even though you're mixing Hebrew and English in one sentence, I think "can food mekabel" or "is food mekabel" is more correct grammatically.

Comment: @robev Yeshivish has its own grammar that follows neither Hebrew nor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rambam Hilchot Tum'at Ochlim 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Defilement_of_Foods.1.1?lang=bi)

> כָּל אֹכֶל הַמְיֻחָד לְמַאֲכַל אָדָם כְּגוֹן לֶחֶם וּבָשָׂר וַעֲנָבִים וְזֵיתִים וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן מְקַבֵּל טֻמְאָה וְכָל שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְיֻחָד לְמַאֲכַל אָדָם הֲרֵי זֶה טָהוֹר וְאֵינוֹ מְקַבֵּל טֻמְאָה אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן חִשֵּׁב עָלָיו וְיִחֲדוֹ לְמַאֲכַל אָדָם
>
> Any food designed for man, such as bread, meat, grapes, olives and the like, is susceptible to uncleanness; whatever is not used as food by man is clean, and is not susceptible to uncleanness unless one has assigned it as food for man.

Comment: BUT there's a lower standard of human food than for other halachos.  Challah 1:8